# Github failed push

Tags: macos, git, github, git-push

So to make a long story short, I've been working on a web app for the past few months. Recently I had to get a new laptop and cloned the repository from github onto my new machine... However whenever I commit changes to my app and attempt to use `git push -u` in the app's root directory i get the following message:

`To git@github.com:acc/etc.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:acc/etc.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.`

but when I try `git pull git@github.com:acc/etc.git master`  I get a message telling me that the pull was aborted.

`From github.com:acc/etc
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
config/routes.rb
test/fixtures/users.yml
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting`

so then i commit my changes using `git commit -m 'fixing'` and then attempt `git pull` again.

however this time I got messages stating that practically all my files had an "Auto-Merging CONFLICT"

am i totally screwed with this particular repository? I'm not really sure what to do since git is still somewhat new to me....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the changes aren't that big, consider making a copy of the entire folder/project in a different directory outside of the project, then `git reset --hard HEAD` will wipe out, erase and delete your recent changes.
You can then apply them again individually using your save3d copies for refernce.
Make sure sure you `git add` before `git commit` of course.
Finally if you get auto commit merge issues you can always just edit the files manually to resolve.

Answer (score 3):

> am i totally screwed with this particular repository?

No, but you will have to do a manual merge, since Git can't figure it out. `git status` will tell you which files need editing. The files themselves contain markers indicating *where* you should edit. When that's done, `git push` should work again.